# Insert data into a column if no data in column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

How do I insert data into a column if that column has no values? This piece of code will not insert any values, unless I take out the if statement. Of course that isn't what I want, since that means each time the code is run, more data will be inserted into the column 'datagroup'.

```
include('dg_config.php');

# select column datagroup from table data
$stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT datagroup FROM data");

$stmt->execute();

# fetch rows from data
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

if (empty($row['datagroup'])){
    $insertdg = "INSERT INTO data (datagroup)
     VALUES ('Data Definitions'),('Policies'),('Systems and Process Documents'),('Purchase Orders'),('Invoices')";
    $db ->exec($insertdg);

}
}
```

P.S **dg_config.php** contains the variable $db which is used for MySQL connection. Also, I have no values in the column so UPDATE won't work.

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: did you try if ($row['datagroup']==''){

Comment: You have more values than columns.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner think they are multiple rows.

Comment: @NigelRen I think they want to concat them into 1 column. Hard to say really what they want to do here. Question's unclear IMHO.

Comment: Not sure what you want. A table is made out of columns and then has multiple rows. How you mean: one column only once? Put a unique key on the column? Do you realise that you're inserting multiple rows into the table? And check your naming. Very confusing to have a table name and column with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if there are no records first and only insert the values then, a quick way from where you are is to say if the `fetch()` fails to retrieve a row then do the insert...

```
include('dg_config.php');

# select column datagroup from table data
$stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT datagroup FROM data");

$stmt->execute();
if ( !$stmt->fetch() ){
    $insertdg = "INSERT INTO data (datagroup)
     VALUES ('Data Definitions'),('Policies'),('Systems and Process Documents'),('Purchase Orders'),('Invoices')";
    $db ->exec($insertdg);

}
// re fetch the data
$stmt->execute();
```

This removes the `while()` loop altogether.

Comment: the data does get inserted into the database but when I try to display it on the table on my web browser, the record 'Data Definitions' is missing. I inserted this code `while($row = $stmt->fetch()){


?>

<tr>
 
 <td><?php echo $row['datagroup'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['dataowner']?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['linkedpg']?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>` after your code.

Comment: Can you check on the database if the value is there

Comment: the values are there but I can't retrieve the first row: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/ncLtzJfG/data.png)

Comment: I've altered the answer slightly, this should re start the fetch.